# How can you move a set of positioned children at the same time?

Tags: html, css

For instance:

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}

#one {
  left: 0
}

#two {
  left: 200px;
}

#three {
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="one" class="inner">first</div>
  <div id="two" class="inner">second</div>
  <div id="three" class="inner">third</div>
</div>
```

And I'd like to do something like `$(#outer).css('left','-200px')` and have all three children move 200px to the left (so that #one is off screen, and #two is where #one was).

Comment: could you show us the issue in fiddle or codepen?

Comment: You would just wrap the children in a container and move that. Also you just used jQuery but haven't tagged this question as jQuery.... So are you asking for it in CSS or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be with only css:

```
#outer
{ 
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fdkrfagk/3/

Comment: I like that this only moves #outer, not moving all three .inner separately.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's as easy as:

```
$('#outer .inner').css('left', '-=200px');
```

Checkout the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qk53ywh/1/) (where I only move the divs 20px to show what it does)

Selecting elements in jQuery is pretty much the same as selecting elements with css (not exactly, but for brevity's sake, it is ;)). So exactly like css, the selector `.inner` selects *all* elements with the class `inner`. Calling the `.css()` function will execute the function for *each* selected element. No need to call `.each()` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".inner").each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var before = parseInt(elem.css('left'), 10);
    elem.css('left', (before - 200) + 'px');
});
```

This function is iterating over all child elements, and calls the inner function on each of them.

`elem` then represents each child. `before` stores the previous value of the `css-left` attribute. (Different for each child)

Then the value is moved 200px to the left.

Another solution is using a **closure**:

```
$('.inner').css('left', function (index, leftValue) {
    return parseInt(leftValue, 10) - 200 + 'px';
});
```